# Sort COUNT(CASE WHEN) results

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am taking a database of statuses and creating the statuses as columns in order to count how many records from a network exist in each status. I'd love to sort the results based on the Partnered column DESC, but I can't figure out how or where to do that??

**Here's my code:**

```
SELECT type,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "NOT_SUBMITTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Not_Submitted,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PARTNERED" THEN storenumber END) AS Partnered,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PENDING" THEN storenumber END) AS Pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "SUSPENDED" THEN storenumber END) AS Suspended,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "REJECTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Rejected,
FROM Programs
GROUP BY 1;
```

Here are my results so far.

| row | type | Not_Submitted | Partnered | Pending | Suspended | Rejected |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | 26 | 473 | 36 | 0 | 374 |
| 2 | def | 2481 | 3943 | 797 | 363 | 1074 |
| 3 | ghi | 0 | 1965 | 0 | 150 | 102 |
| 4 | jkl | 1231 | 1851 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just add `ORDER BY Partnered DESC` as in below example

```
SELECT type,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "NOT_SUBMITTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Not_Submitted,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PARTNERED" THEN storenumber END) AS Partnered,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PENDING" THEN storenumber END) AS Pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "SUSPENDED" THEN storenumber END) AS Suspended,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "REJECTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Rejected,
FROM Programs
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Partnered DESC
```

Meantime, consider also below option

```
SELECT type,
    COUNTIF(status = "NOT_SUBMITTED") AS Not_Submitted,
    COUNTIF(status = "PARTNERED") AS Partnered,
    COUNTIF(status = "PENDING") AS Pending,
    COUNTIF(status = "SUSPENDED") AS Suspended,
    COUNTIF(status = "REJECTED") AS Rejected,
FROM Programs
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY Partnered DESC
```

and finally - try below one (it is my preferred option)

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT type, storenumber, status FROM Programs)
PIVOT (
    COUNT(DISTINCT storenumber) 
    FOR status IN ("NOT_SUBMITTED", "PARTNERED", "PENDING", "SUSPENDED", "REJECTED")
)
ORDER BY PARTNERED DESC
```

Comment: All 3 solutions worked great! 

#1, <facepalm> over here for not realizing I could just sort by my newly defined "Partnered" column.

#2, I never thought of doing COUNTIF for this. I've used the COUNT(CASE WHEN) for a few other queries, now I'm going to revisit using COUNTIF. Thank you!

#3, I never knew you could PIVOT like that with SQL. It's funny, when I was describing what I wanted to do, I even said to someone, I just want to pivot the data like in excel. Didn't even realize there was an operator to do the same in SQL. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: glad it worked for you. Consider also voting up the answer if it really helped :o)

Comment: You got it! :) :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#standardSQL
WITH table as (
SELECT type,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "NOT_SUBMITTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Not_Submitted,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PARTNERED" THEN storenumber END) AS Partnered,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "PENDING" THEN storenumber END) AS Pending,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "SUSPENDED" THEN storenumber END) AS Suspended,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN status = "REJECTED" THEN storenumber END) AS Rejected,
FROM Programs
GROUP BY 1)
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY Partnered DESC
```

I put your query in a subquery then querying the subquery to be ordered by Partnered DESC

Comment: Thank you!! This worked, but the below solutions were a bit easier. Thank you for sharing, this reminded me about leveraging subqueries as well. I hadn't thought of that as an option until you mentioned it.